# Duplicate tag [vms] and [openvms]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

We have these two tags with the *same* description:

- [vms](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vms) with 7 questions
- [openvms](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/openvms) with 6 questions

[One question](https://serverfault.com/q/151490/89813) even has both tags.

Suggestion: Make [openvms](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/openvms) the synonym of [vms](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vms).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should be synonymed the other way around. The product was originally VMS and then it became OpenVMS which I believe it is still called. Other than that I don't see any real reason not to do this.

Comment: I don't see why a synonym should be done, just retagging those 7 questions and crossing fingers until 3:00 UTC

Comment: @Braiam a synonym is a long term fix as I see it, we don't want to re-have this discussion in two week as the tag can be re-used again

Comment: Considering that the [newest vms question was asked on '13](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vms?sort=newest) and it's a 7 years old tag, I doubt that it will be useful on the short term, much less the long one.

Comment: @Braiam I prefer the synonym's idea, but maybe you should post that as an answer, and let the community decide, as I agree the tag usage is old.

Comment: @Braiam: Agreed, but OpenVMS on AMD64 is coming. :-)

Comment: OpenVMS hasn't been a force for a long time i can't see an AMD64 version being much more than a niche hobbyist thing.

Comment: Done diddly doodly.

Comment: @Braiam I am a bit at a loss here. What is at 3:00 UTC?

Comment: @M.Glatki the time where most script runs on SE.

Answer (score 2):

Creating synonym is overkilling it: it needs 5 users with a score of 5 on the said tag to be done, or a moderator (the last one is very busy) compared with a single retag that requires 2 minutes and a single user. It's better to just retag them and be done with it, which seems sensible considering that nobody has asked a vms tagged question in years, it's unlikely to be recreated.